# Did Luke lose his X-Wing on Cloud City?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back, luke-skywalker

Luke flies to Cloud City near the end of *The Empire Strikes Back* to rescue his friends. R2-D2 follows him into the facility when they land.

R2-D2 then follows Lando and company out to the Millennium Falcon. Injured and bewildered after his battle with Darth Vader, Luke is rescued by the Millennium Falcon.

Where does Luke’s X-Wing end up? Gone? Stolen? Destroyed by the Empire, so that means he’s issued a new X-Wing in *Return of the Jedi*?

Or is there a Canon or Legends novelization that spells out what happened?

Canon or Legends answers are acceptable.

Answer (score 16):

In issues [3](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_(2020)_3) and [4](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_(2020)_4) of the current (2020) [*Star Wars* comic series from Marvel](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_(Marvel_2020)), Luke, Leia and Lando return to Cloud City for various reasons.

Along the way, Luke picks up his X-Wing.

[image: Star Wars v3 #4 p13]

Comment: Don't forget that your answers need to stand for the ages, Calling it the "current" series is a hostage to fortune since if you wait five years, there's going to be a new current comic.

Comment: I think they need to hire new artists for that comic book.  Luke and Lando are bad enough, but the guy in the background appears to have candles or dynamite sticks stuck in his ears - or maybe sausages.

Comment: @JRE Is there reason to believe that he does not, in fact, have candles or dynamite sticks stuck in his ears?  Sausages is just ridiculous.

Comment: @JRE That's apparently [Lobot](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lobot), good question as to what's going on with his head - is he maybe trying a new hairstyle?

Comment: The Imperials had wired Lobot directly into Cloud City's systems via a bunch of cables into his head. Lando cut him loose, leaving the stubs of those cables hanging off.